# getIem method from MediaBrowserCompat support services

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediasession

In my app I have to get media Items from a connected service, then to get them from the service Google's documentation says I use the getItem method. But, as the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/MediaBrowserCompat#getItem(java.lang.String,%2520android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat.ItemCallback)) says, there are some services that not support this method, and in my case, for now, the only service that not supports it is bluetooth. How can I have a list of "no get items support" services?

I searched on the docs a method to have a list of non support services or a method to check if the service supports and I didn't had success. Also I though of make a list of non supported services and check if the current service is listed, but the problem on this approach is that if the user install another application that not supports getItem, it won't be listed and it will crash when it tries to call get items

I want to find a more efficient method to check if the service supports getItem

Comment: I have the same problem. Can someone help?